# Optimize/Improve Performance of PSQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, psql

Is there any way to optimize the below query further?

```
select *,RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY jsondata->> 'id' ORDER BY pid desc ) as rank_number 
from xyz 
where jsondata ->> 'id' in (select jsondata ->> 'id' 
                        from xyz 
                            where pid= a) 
and pid <= a
```

Few details about the columns:
jsondata[jsonb], geo[geometry], pid[bigint]

'a' is some random integer value.

Table Structure

```
Table "public.xyz"
  Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                                       Default                                        
----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 gid      | text                     |           | not null | 
 jsondata | jsonb                    |           |          | 
 geo      | geometry.                |           |          | 
 pid      | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 i        | bigint                   |           | not null | 

Indexes:
    "xyzidx" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
    "idx" btree (gid)
```

EXPLAIN results for query:

```
WindowAgg  (cost=2411885.51..2503195.23 rows=669100 width=1669)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=2411885.51..2489813.23 rows=669100 width=1661)
Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Sort  (cost=2410885.48..2411582.46 rows=278792 width=1661)
Sort Key: ((xyz.jsondata ->> 'id'::text)), xyz.pid DESC
  ->  Parallel Hash Semi Join  (cost=986665.67..1983541.38 rows=278792 width=1661)
Hash Cond: ((xyz.jsondata ->> 'id'::text) = (xyz.jsondata ->> 'id'::text))
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on xyz  (cost=0.00..986664.95 rows=557584 width=1629)
Filter: (pid <= 97786)
  ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=986664.95..986664.95 rows=58 width=1536)
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on xyz  (cost=0.00..986664.95 rows=58 width=1536)
Filter: (pid = 97786)
```

I tried the below approach but i didn't help me much

```
select A.jsondata,A.geo,RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY A.jsondata->> 'id' ORDER BY A.pid desc ) as rank_number 
from xyz A,xyz B  
Where A.jsondata->>'id' = B.jsondata->>'id' 
And B.pid = a
And A.pid<= a
```

Comment: what is the data type of the jsondata column? an execution plan is an essential tool when optimizing.

Comment: Your question is not very useful without basic performance information. Consider instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: Also, is `a` a column of the table?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: updated question with more details

Answer (score 0):

Your query predicate (a/k/a WHERE condition) `jsondata ->> 'id' in (something)` can't be satisfied without scanning through the table looking at every `jsondata` column. That takes time.

You might be able to put an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) on  `jsondata ->> 'id'`. Try this.

```
CREATE INDEX jsondata_id ON xyz (jsondata ->> 'id');
```

If you can get that to work it will help performance.

Comment: I tried adding given index on the table but there is no improvement in the performance.